# CSS center image in a clipped parent div

Tags: css

How can I center an `img` in a parent `div` tag which is set to `overflow: hidden`. That is, what I want is to clip the image but clip on both the left/right so the middle of the image is shown.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <img/>
</div>
```

Then styles something like:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  /* position details here */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper img {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -??; //what here?
}
```

`-50%` would be the width of the parent, but I want the width of the img itself.

Firefox supported CSS is acceptable.

Comment: check my answer Or http://jsfiddle.net/Us3Qh/ solution of your question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj

use text-align , line-height , vertical-align and negative margin. img virtually reduced to zero, will center itself.

```
.wrapper {
  width:300px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:solid;
  margin:2em auto;
  overflow:visible; /* let's see what we slice off */
}
img {margin:-100%;vertical-align:middle;

  /* to show whats been cut off */
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

For horizontal only :

```
  .wrapper {
      width:300px;
      text-align:center;
      border:solid;
      margin:2em auto;
      overflow:hidden
    }
    img {
      margin:0 -100%;
      vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Comment: My wrapping box does not have a fixed height, it adapts to its outer div's height.

Comment: so remove line-height and set margin as : margin:0 -100%; just use half of it :) , the horizontal values that matters to you . too much info kills info ? ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus do you know if this technique is cross browser / device compatible?

Comment: @Lando It use to be, only MAC browser untested by myslf but never heard so far it was an issue there. Do not hesitate to feed back here :). Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
display:block;
margin:0px auto;
```

to ".wrapper img"

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Us3Qh/)

its solve your problem

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <img  border="3"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
   /*position: absolute;*/
   /* position details here */
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align:center
}
.wrapper img {
  height: 100%;
}
```