# Stretch and center image of unknown size

Tags: html, css, image

I have different images of various, unknown sizes (bigger, smaller, etc.). What I want is to stretch and center those images within a container of a known size while keeping the aspect ratio of the images.

That is:

- if images are bigger, they should get resized to fit within the container's size with their given aspect ratio and be centered.
- if images are smaller, they should simply kept as-is and being centered within the container's size

Any idea?

Comment: You can start with setting `max-height:100%` and `max-width:100%` to the images, that will handle the bigger ones. You would need to set a width and height on the parent element.

Comment: but how are the images supposed to keep their aspect ratio then?

Comment: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7fjgkdy/) for a working sample

Comment: @MasterOfDisaster image will keep their ratio if you only use max-height or max-width, just test it to fin out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code as example:

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <span class="imghelper"></span>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/30x30"/>
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <span class="imghelper"></span>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300"/>
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <span class="imghelper"></span>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x150"/>
</div>
```

Use css like so:

```
.imagecontainer{
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color:#656565;
    text-align:center;
}
.imghelper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.imagecontainer img{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This keeps the images at the correct ratios, but doesn't allow them to be bigger than the contianer, and centers smaller images: See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7fjgkdy/) for a live demo

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS `max-width` on the `img` elements, live demo http://jsfiddle.net/exaxq5ho/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/600x100"/>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x100"/>
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a container of a known height can see a line-height applied to vertical center inline boxes.
Max-height and eventually max-width if width is known too can be used to shrink image.

negative margin could allow image to grow wider than box .

Container could be allowed to see width grow.
here a few examples :

```css
picture.knownheight {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  line-height:96px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 1em;;
  overflow:hidden;
}
picture.knownheight.auto {
  width:auto;
  min-width:100px;
}
picture.knownheight.maxW img {
  max-width:100%;
}
picture.knownheight.minH img {
  min-height:100%;
}

picture.knownheight img {
  vertical-align:middle;
  max-height:100%;
  margin:0 -100%;/* keeps img at center and clip them*/
}
```

```html
<h1>max-height, max-width, center </h1>
<picture class="knownheight maxW">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight maxW">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight maxW">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight maxW">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight maxW">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/340"/>
</picture>
<h1>max-height, center, clip sides </h1>
<picture class="knownheight">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/340"/>
</picture>
<h1>max-height, min-height to stretch , center & clip sides </h1>
<picture class="knownheight minH ">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight minH ">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight minH ">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight minH ">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight minH ">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/340"/>
</picture>
<h1>max-height, min-height to stretch container. center img </h1>
<picture class="knownheight minH auto">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight minH auto">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight minH auto">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight minH auto">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/450"/>
</picture>
<picture class="knownheight minH auto">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/340"/>
</picture>
```

inspired from [Clipping image in center without clip CSS](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/BdtEj)  from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337635/css-center-image-in-a-clipped-parent-div/)